# How can I find all the implicit WPF Styles in my solution?

Tags: wpf

I'd like to use Visual Studio's Find in Files (or some other mechanism) to find all the implicit WPF Styles in my solution (all the styles that do not have a Key and thus apply themselves globally). How can this be accomplished?

Comment: They do have a Key, default one. Actually, when u code something like `<Style TargetType={x:Type TextBlock} .. />` WITHOUT SPECIFING KEY it gonna work exactly the same way. I might be wrong, but I assume that the name of the Control ('TextBox') is a Key. U can look through documentation to find a precise answer.

Comment: Have you checked the answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to check the `Key` of the `Style` resource. If the value of `Key` is of type `System.Type` and its base class is `System.Windows.FrameworkElement`, it means it is an implicit `Style`.

```
static List<Style> _styles = new List<Style>();
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Check for Application
    var appResDict = Application.Current.Resources;
    foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in appResDict)
    {
        if ((entry.Key is System.Type) && ((Type)entry.Key).IsSubclassOf(typeof(System.Windows.FrameworkElement)))
            _styles.Add((Style)entry.Value);
    }

    // Check for Window
    var resDict = this.Resources;
    foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in resDict)
    {
        if ((entry.Key is System.Type) && ((Type)entry.Key).IsSubclassOf(typeof(System.Windows.FrameworkElement)))
            _styles.Add((Style)entry.Value);
    }

    // Check for all other controls
    MainWindow.EnumVisual(this);

    MessageBox.Show(_styles.Count.ToString());
}

// Enumerate all the descendants of the visual object.
static public void EnumVisual(Visual myVisual)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(myVisual); i++)
    {
        // Retrieve child visual at specified index value.
        Visual childVisual = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(myVisual, i);

        // Check for implicit style
        if (childVisual is FrameworkElement)
        {
            FrameworkElement elem = (FrameworkElement)childVisual;
            var resDict = elem.Resources;

            foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in resDict)
            {
                if ((entry.Key is System.Type) && ((Type)entry.Key).IsSubclassOf(typeof(System.Windows.FrameworkElement)))
                    _styles.Add((Style)entry.Value);
            }
        }


        // Enumerate children of the child visual object.
        EnumVisual(childVisual);
    }
}
```